# How can I send multi NSURLConnection requests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to do something for several steps:

1. send an `NSURLConnection` request
2. receive the data
3. after receive the data, send another request in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method
4. receive the data again

How can I do that? Or is there better method than sending `NSURLConnection` request?

Comment: As you said *after receive the data, send another request in connectionDidFinishLoading method* will help you.

Comment: You can have many of these active concurrently as well.

Comment: Your method is simple and should work fine. But DavidH is right that you _can_ do them concurrently, if you want, but if you do so, be aware that (a) you need some object that encapsulates the connection, it's responseData, etc.; and (b) you really don't want to do more than 4 or 5 concurrently. By the way, you might want to consider a library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to simplify the process. By the way, what are you downloading and for what purpose? Our counsel might change depending upon what you're downloading (e.g. images for tableview? xml? json?).

Comment: I would strongly recommend AFNetworking too.  It works very well for us.